# curl with data encode url in R

Tags: r, curl

data-encode-url in R

```
curl "https://www.zopim.com/api/v2/chats/search" \
-G --data-urlencode "q=timestamp:[2016-02-02T16:00:00 TO *] \
-v -u {email_address}:{password}
```

How to convert `--data-urlencode` this in R?

**This is what I have so far:** without the search part

```
  chats <<- getURL('https://www.zopim.com/api/v2/chats/', verbose = TRUE, userpwd = "username:pwd", httpauth = 1L)
```

**where and how to add**

```
--data-urlencode "q=timestamp:[2016-02-02T16:00:00 TO *]
```

**in R**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
library(httr)

GET(
  "https://www.zopim.com/api/v2/chats/search",
  query=list(
    q="timestamp:[2016-02-02T16:00:00 TO *] AND rating:good"
  ),
  authenticate("you@example.com", "yourpassword"),
  verbose()
) -> result

content(result, as="parsed")
## $results
## list()
## 
## $count
## [1] 0
## 
## $prev_url
## NULL
## 
## $next_url
## NULL
```

Remove the `verbose()` in production.